# How should I reduce number of groups in regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to find telephone numbers in string. I use the following code

```
import re
a = '88005553535'
test = re.compile('(\+?[0-9]{1}( |-)?([0-9]{3}|\\([0-9]{3}\\))( |-)?[0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{2}( |-)?[0-9]{2})+')
print(test.findall(a))
```

but I have `[('88005553535', '', '800', '', '', '')]` in result. I realize it happens due to existence of several groups in regex, but I don't understand clearly why do they appear. How should I avoid it?

Comment: use `[ -]` instead of `( |-)`

Comment: `( |-)` is a *capturing group*. *`re.findall` returns captured texts if the regex pattern contains capturing groups in it*... *convert all capturing groups into non-capturing (that is, replace `(` with `(?:`) unless there are backreferences that refer to the group values in the pattern...*